# Python's unittest doesn't initialize logger as expected

Tags: python, logging

My `unittest` module breaks when testing my main file because my main file references a logger that was not initialized.

We have the following simple example.

logger_main.py:

```
import logging

def some_func():
    logger.info(__name__ + " started ")
    # Do something
    logger.info(__name__ + " finished ")
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    some_func()
```

logger_main_tests.py:

```
import unittest
import logging
from logger_main import some_func

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def testName(self):
        self.assertEqual(some_func(), 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

logger_main.py runs as expected, however, logger_main_tests.py gives the following error.

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

======================================================================
ERROR: testName (logger_main_tests.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspaces\PythonPlayground\DataStoreHierarchy\logger_main_tests.py", line 11, in testName
    self.assertEqual(some_func(), 1)
  File "C:\workspaces\PythonPlayground\DataStoreHierarchy\logger_main.py", line 4, in some_func
    logger.info(__name__ + " started ")
NameError: name 'logger' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The error makes sense since `some_func()` is trying to use `logger` that doesn't exists in its scope and I would like to figure out how to set up my unittests with a logger (set at the `DEBUG` level) so that any `logger.info` or `logger.debug` statement inside of my functions (such as `some_func()`) in logger_main.py would be printed out at the appropriate level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move this line outside of your main declaration.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

The main will defined where the logs goes, but should not be used to defined the logger. Your module should declare the logger in its global context.

You can (and should) defined as many loggers as you need, it is common to have one per file or class and declaring it after you imports so it is available anywhere in the code that follow.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def some_func():
    .....
```

Comment: Would you provide exactly how my logger_main_tests.py should look like for this to work? I tried moving that line around without success.

Comment: Oh, you meant to move that line in the logger_main.py file. Thanks this makes sense now!

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 for logger_main_tests.py, simply remove `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` as you never use the logger in this file.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `logger` is only being defined when `__name__ == "__main__"`.

Generally you'll define one logger per file, something like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

At the top of the file, after the imports.

Also, notice that the `logger` defined in `Test.setUp` is local to the function, so it won't do anything.

Comment: Would you provide exactly how my logger_main_tests.py should look like for this to work? I tried moving that line around without success.